# Best practice for controlling Pytorch's neural network layers' number and size?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm looking for best practices for controlling/adjusting the number of layers and also their sizes in Pytorch neural networks in general.

I have a configuration file in which I specify values for particular experiment variables. Additionally, I'd like to have an option in this file to determine the number and size of Pytorch's neural networks layers.

Current solution:

*config.py*

```
ACTOR_LAYER_SIZES: (128, 256, 128)
```

*network.py*

```
# input_size: int
# output_size: int
# layer_sizes = ACTOR_LAYER_SIZES

    layers = [
        nn.Linear(input_size, layer_sizes[0]),
        nn.ReLU(),
        BatchNorm1d(layer_sizes[0]),
    ]
    layers += list(
        chain.from_iterable(
            [
                [
                    nn.Linear(n_size, next_n_size),
                    nn.ReLU(),
                    BatchNorm1d(next_n_size),
                ]
                for n_size, next_n_size in zip(layer_sizes, layer_sizes[1:])
            ]
        )
    )
    layers += [(nn.Linear(layer_sizes[-1], output_size))]

    network = nn.Sequential(*layers)
```

I wonder if using `chain.from_iterable` may be considered here as the best practice in general. Furthermore, this code appears to be a little lengthy. Maybe there is a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following snippet for this task:

```
import torch.nn as nn

num_inputs = 10
num_outputs = 5
hidden_layers = (128, 256, 128)
activation = nn.ReLU

layers = (
    num_inputs,
    *hidden_layers,
    num_outputs
)

network_architecture = []
for i in range(1, len(layers)):
    network_architecture.append(nn.Linear(layers[i - 1], layers[i]))
    if i < len(layers) - 1:  # for regression tasks prevent the last layer from getting an activation function 
        network_architecture.append(activation())
    
model = nn.Sequential(*network_architecture)
```

The `if` statement prevents the output layer from getting an activation function. This is necessary when you do **regression**. If you want to do **classification**, however, you need some kind of activation function (e.g. softmax) there to output discrete classes.

Using a `for` loop in conjunction with an `if` statement instead of `chain.from_iterable` has the advantage that it is universally and intuitively understood. Furthermore, by moving the activation function out of the loop, it is configurable.

Adding the `BatchNorm1d` layer should be straightforward.